# RAM memory usage is showing as 21g for a process where as Heap memory usage for the same process is 4gb. Where the remaining memory is going to?

Tags: java, wildfly, heap-memory, ram

I have recently upgraded application server of a java application from JBoss to Wildfly. The application starts fine but RAM is filling up so fast. It is showing as 21gb used out of 23gb with free command.

[image]

When I look at the processes using top command, the java process in question is taking 20.7g

[image]

But, when I try to debug the remote java process using jconsole, heap memory usage is ~4g

[image]

If heap memory usage is 4g, then how come top command is showing that the same process memory usage is 20.7g and total RAM usage is 21g? What am I missing here and how to resolve this memory issue?